# jQuery Debounce On A Link

Tags: javascript, jquery

My purpose is to prevent client click on a specific link repeatedly. Would like to delay it like 2 seconds. I am not able to figure it out.

```
$('.a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('.a').on("click", $.debounce(5000, true, function(){
    $('.a').unbind('click');
}));
```

Am I missing something on the reference docs?

reference: http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/docs/files/jquery-ba-throttle-debounce-js.html

Comment: what is the end goal exactly?

Comment: Goal: to prevent spammy clicks on a link

Comment: So you need to wait a full 2 seconds before clicking again?

Comment: Yes. i will need this, not 2 secs, like 0.5

Comment: well you have it set for 5 seconds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be something like this:

```
var callback = function () {
    console.log( new Date(). toLocaleString()); 
}

//$.debounce(milliseconds, fire right away, function to execute)
var fnc = $.debounce( 500, true,  callback );
$(".a").on("click", fnc);
```

Comment: thanks for that. I'm adjusting the function for my purpose, then let you know the results.